# How to extend axios to send request with PROPFIND method (Typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

I'm trying to send a request to `WEBDAV` with a method `PROPFIND` using `axios`

```
        const response = await axios({
        method: 'PROPFIND',
        url: path,
        data: `<?xml version="1.0"?>
            <d:propfind  xmlns:d="DAV:"
                xmlns:oc="http://owncloud.org/ns"
                xmlns:nc="http://nextcloud.org/ns"
                xmlns:ocs="http://open-collaboration-services.org/ns">
            <d:prop>
                <oc:fileid />
                <oc:foreign-id />
            </d:prop>
            </d:propfind>`,
    });
```

But `typescript` analyzer tell me that `axios` type `Method` can't be `PROPFIND`
https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/bbfd5b1395699ae6290a01f51e0e1b66897099fd/index.d.ts#L24

Comment: PROPFIND is not HTTP method, so you cant send it using axios method prop

Comment: the typescript analyzer is going to do that because PROPFIND is not defined as a type on the list. it will still work though. you might have to suppress your warnings if it's not compiling.